# Hacer union de 2 div o crear algo semejante a una pestaña

Tags: css, css3, selectores-css

Estoy maquetando un diseño, pero no he podido avanzar porque no se como podría implementar una pestaña al `div` o lo que se haría en el diseño es una unión de 2 cajas, no se si usando los pseudo elementos del propio `div` o habría otra forma de realizarlo.

> Lo que estoy intentado hacer es esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero agregar la parte donde esta escrito **live** y donde están los botones a la derecha, como podría hacerlo con `css`?.

Este es el `div` al que le quiero agregar lo anterior:

```
<div class="col-6 align-self-center">
     <div><textarea class="bg-main border-0 w-75" cols="30" rows="10" disabled></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por que no agregas el HTML y el CSS de lo que has intentado para en base a eso poderte ayudar

Comment: es que no he intentado nada porque no se que hacer alli ni con que, igual ya te agrego el html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo lo resolvería usando los **pseudo-elementos** `after` y `before` utilizando la posición absoluta para ellos y relativa para el `div` padre, así:

```css
div#contenedor{
  background: #322d48;
  padding: 15px;
}

div#subcontenedor{
  width: calc(100% - 25px - 30px);
  background: #264541;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2c7551;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

div#subcontenedor:before{
  content: 'Live';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #264541;
  left: 0;
  top: -25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

div#subcontenedor:after{
     content: url(http://lorempixel.com/25/25)url(http://lorempixel.com/25/25);
    position: absolute;
    right: -35px;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #264541;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2c7551;
    height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 align-self-center" id="contenedor">
  <div id="subcontenedor"><textarea class="bg-main border-0 w-75" cols="30" rows="10" disabled></textarea></div>
</div>
```

A continuación te agrego otra forma de hacerlo desde la cual podrías darle interacción a los botones que se encuentran en el lado derecho de la tarjeta:

```css
div#contenedor{
  background: #322d48;
  padding: 15px;
}

div#subcontenedor{
  width: calc(100% - 25px - 30px);
  background: #264541;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2c7551;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

div#subcontenedor #superior{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #264541;
  left: 0;
  top: -25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

div#subcontenedor #lateral{
    position: absolute;
    right: -35px;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #264541;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2c7551;
    height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 align-self-center" id="contenedor">
  <div id="subcontenedor">
    <textarea class="bg-main border-0 w-75" cols="30" rows="10" disabled></textarea>
    
    <div id="superior">Live</div>
    <div id="lateral">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/25/25">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/25/25">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, tenia algunas ideas que era con pseudo elementos.

Comment: @AsdrubalHernandez pero ojo, respondí tu pregunta y resolví de una forma hacer ese diseño que tienes, existen muchas formas, si a esos botones que están al lado derecho les quieres añadir interacciones con el usuario (eventos) entonces se deben cambiar el after y before por div, me hago entender?

Comment: Me podrias escribir la opcion para la otra forma, para tenerla en cuenta en futuros cambios. Te lo agradezco

Comment: @AsdrubalHernandez claro, pero puedo hacerlo nuevamente el lunes que esté en la oficina, desde el móvil es complicado

Comment: vale no hay problema, muchisimas gracias

Comment: @AsdrubalHernandez te he editado la respuesta con la otra forma en la cual podrías aplicar eventos a las imágenes laterales, saludos!